# PhoneGap/Cordova: Fine in Simulator, suddenly not working on device: Can't find jQuery

Tags: jquery, ios, cordova, jquery-mobile, cordova-2.0.0

This just suddenly began happening: my boss took her phone with the development copy of the app on a short business trip, and reported this error a couple days into the trip. I assumed I had made some changes to the json returning from the server and that broke it, but now that I have it back, it doesn't seem to be related to my work on the server at all.

Here is the error message I get in the console:

```
Error in success callback: Geolocation3 = ReferenceError: Can't find variable: jQuery
```

or

```
Error in success callback: Geolocation3 = ReferenceError: Can't find variable: $
```

So clearly, it just can't find jQuery. It executes 'deviceReady' just fine. But it works fine in the simulator. I am using the jQuery CDN for both jQM and jQ and can access both via a browser.

So what gives? Why would it suddenly not be able to find jQuery - and only on the device?

I see A LOT of similar questions on the web, but none of them have a clear answer. Some is "clean and rebuild" others are simple typos.... but nothing for this. It's not a location permissions issue. It's not a connection issue. It's not a url whitelist issue.

Your help is appreciated as always. Thanks!

---

I'll give as much code as I can below:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <title>XXXXXX</title> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/themes/app-2012-11-30.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="spec/lib/photoswipe/photoswipe.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
    <!-- cordova -->
    <script src="cordova-2.1.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!-- jquery -->
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Google -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"></script>
    <!-- Add ons -->
    <script src="spec/lib/photoswipe/lib/klass.min.js"></script>
    <script src="spec/lib/photoswipe/code.photoswipe.jquery-3.0.5.js"></script>
    <!-- Objects -->
    <script src="js/map.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/prefs.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/search.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/storage.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
    <script src="js/helpers.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/player.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
    <script src="js/record.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  
    <script src="js/connection.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
    <script src="js/location.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  
    <script src="js/header-footer.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/featured.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/list.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/index.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
        function onDeviceReady(){
            console.log('device ready');
            storageSetUp();
            checkConnection();
            getLocation();
            showFeatured();
            getSetUp();
            clUpdate();
            $(document).bind( 'mobileinit', function(){
                $.mobile.defaultPageTransition = "none";
                $.mobile.loader.prototype.options.textVisible=false;
                $.mobile.loader.prototype.options.html = '<div class="loading"></div>';
                $.mobile.pushStateEnabled = false;
            });
            $(document).bind('pagebeforeshow',function(){
                setHeaderFooterInfo();
            });         
        }
    </script>
```

getLocation is in a .js file. You see the function getStreetAddress there, it contains an ajax call ($.ajax or jQuery.ajax) and this is where it gives the error.

```
function getLocation()
{
    gLAttempt++;
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onLocationSuccess, onLocationError);
} 

// onSuccess Geolocation
function onLocationSuccess(position)
{
    var lat = position.coords.latitude;
    var lng = position.coords.longitude;
    Storage.location.lat = parseFloat(lat.toFixed(6));
    Storage.location.lng = parseFloat(lng.toFixed(6));
    Storage.location.coords = lat.toFixed(6) + ',' + lng.toFixed(6);
    if(ajax_rg == null){
        getStreetAddress(Storage.location.coords);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

2 possible scenarios which I can think of:

1. iOS devices are case sensitive with file/folder names. Make sure that you use the same case for all added files and folders. Remember that iOS simulator is case insensitive. so case insensitive file reference will work on simulator but will not work in device.
2. Remove the jQuery reference from the CDN and add it locally. When you are packaging the app and deploying it, doesn't really make sense to use the CDN. It could happen that your onDeviceReady event is fired but jQuery files are not downloaded from the CDN...

Comment: That was it. Thank you so much, I was really banging my head against the wall on that one. I don't understand how it could have suddenly taken longer to download than it used to. But there you have it. Thanks!

Comment: Oh, by "that was it" I mean keeping the files locally instead of trying to download them via the CDN. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

I had he same problem recently. I spent hours trying to figure out what was wrong and when I compared my new files with the old ones I realized that one html file name was `sidebar.html` while it was referred in the code as `sideBar.html`.

Case sensitive was the only issue.